# Thrift Required Field C++

Tags: c++, protocols, thrift

```
Thrift File:
struct Sub {
1: required i32 number
}

struct Message {
1: required Sub sub
}

Message m;
m.write(protocol.get());
Message parsedM;
parsedM.read(protocol2.get());
std::cout << parsedM.sub.number;
```

[SourceCode](http://nopaste.info/b270631dbd.html)

Should not Thrift raise an error or is there any other possibiliy to properly check if all required field have been set?
Otherwise I see no real point in that keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Yes, you should get a `TProtocolException::INVALID_DATA` if the data are not present while deserializing. That's not the case in your example, so you don't get the exception.

### Long answer

This is one of the generated C++ `read()` methods based on your IDL. Watch out for `isset_number` and how it is used:

```
uint32_t Sub::read(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot) {

  uint32_t xfer = 0;
  std::string fname;
  ::apache::thrift::protocol::TType ftype;
  int16_t fid;

  xfer += iprot->readStructBegin(fname);

  using ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolException;

  bool isset_number = false;

  while (true)
  {
    xfer += iprot->readFieldBegin(fname, ftype, fid);
    if (ftype == ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STOP) {
      break;
    }
    switch (fid)
    {
      case 1:
        if (ftype == ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_I32) {
          xfer += iprot->readI32(this->number);
          isset_number = true;
        } else {
          xfer += iprot->skip(ftype);
        }
        break;
      default:
        xfer += iprot->skip(ftype);
        break;
    }
    xfer += iprot->readFieldEnd();
  }

  xfer += iprot->readStructEnd();

  if (!isset_number)
    throw TProtocolException(TProtocolException::INVALID_DATA);
  return xfer;
}
```

### So why does it work in your example?

As we have seen, `required` fields are expected to be present in the deserialized data, while `optional` (and default) fields may be missing. But fields marked `required` (and default fields) are also **always written** to the transport, `optional` only when a value has been assigned. Hence you read the data that you serialized before:

```
uint32_t Sub::write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const {
  uint32_t xfer = 0;
  xfer += oprot->writeStructBegin("Sub");

  xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("number", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_I32, 1);
  xfer += oprot->writeI32(this->number);
  xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();

  xfer += oprot->writeFieldStop();
  xfer += oprot->writeStructEnd();
  return xfer;
}
```

Note that Thrift does not care about whether the field contains *valid* data. It's all about the serializing aspect.

### Recommended reading

[Diwaker Gupta's "Missing Guide"](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/) explains the pros ands cons of `required` quite good.

Comment: Too bad there is no validation mechanism in thrift, but might be a design issue.

Comment: @MichaelLatz - I have been using thrift for 3 years, never noticed an issue in this area.  But if you need it - implement it and submit a patch, as long as it doesn't break current functionality (i.e. optional) I don't think there would be an objection.

Comment: Maybe, yes. One of the main intentions is to stay lightweight, as described in http://thrift.apache.org/about - which implies, that some design decisions were made towards that goal. Whether or not a particular design decision is an "issue", is somewhat subjective and can be matter of discussion. Thrift is not intended to be the proverbial Jack of all trades + master of none. OTOH, we are still adding functionality. Bottom line: Submitting a patch is a good idea to start discussion.